# Hexadecimal byte array from a Midi event to int

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte, midi

I'm trying to retrieve the tempo of a midi file through the `javax.midi` library.

```
MidiMessage message = event.getMessage();
if(message instanceof MetaMessage)
 MetaMessage mm = (MetaMessage) message;
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mm.getData()));
}
```

What I am expected to receive is an array of three ex, because the Set Tempo meta message (which is this case, has just 3 bytes specifying a miliseconds amount.
This is how the midi event returns

```
0x07 0xA1 0x20
```

So if you join them you have 0x07A120 which is 500,000 ms, but Java returns in the print

```
[7, -95, 32]
```

First of all it is parsing it to decimal, and then I need to get this 500,000 number. I don't know how to do it because first I need to join all the hex, and then I will have the number, but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Numbers are numbers. How they're printed is relevant only when... printing them. If you need to pass them around they are just numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MetaMessage.getData()` returns a byte array, which you turn into a list of bytes using `Arrays.asList()`, that's why you print a list of bytes.

Below is a method that compute the tempo in beats per minute from a TEMPO MetaMessage. The `mspq` variable (milliseconds per quarter) is the value you seek.

```
/**
 * Get the tempo in BPM coded in a Tempo Midi message.
 *
 * @param tempoMsg Must be a tempo MetaMessage (type=81)
 * @return
 */
static public int getTempoInBPM(MetaMessage tempoMsg)
{
    byte[] data = tempoMsg.getData();
    if (tempoMsg.getType() != 81 || data.length != 3)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("tempoMsg=" + tempoMsg);   
    }
    int mspq = ((data[0] & 0xff) << 16) | ((data[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (data[2] & 0xff);
    int tempo = Math.round(60000001f / mspq);
    return tempo;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab-X/blob/master/Midi/src/org/jjazz/midi/api/MidiUtilities.java) you'll find some more Midi utilities in java.

Answer (score -1):

```
int tempo = new BigInteger(mm.getData()).intValue();
```

would be simpler